# Como hacer operaciones matematicas con JS o PHP pero que sean en formato moneda

Tags: php, javascript

Muy buen dia, necesito hacer un formulario sencillo en html donde pueda hacer operaciones matematicas pero con formato moneda.   He intentado con muchos codigos que he encontrado en internet pero ninguno da el resultado deseado.

Ya tengo el código tanto en php como en JavaScript de operaciones matemáticas ( 1000 + 1000 = 2000)   pero no encuentro la forma para que las cantidades tengan formato de moneda.  (1.000 + 1.000  = 2.000)

Alguien que ya halla hecho algo así que me pueda brindar una guía.

Mil gracias y un saludo desde Bogotá.

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], la idea es mostrar que llevas intentado en alguno o los 2 lenguajes así como la ayuda específica que ocupas para resolver lo que no logras hacer

Answer (score 0):

Esto te podría servir.

```
var num = 123456.789;

console.log(num.toLocaleString('es-ES', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }));
// → 123.456,79 €
```

En la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString) tienes mas detalles.